# How to get data out of a reusable StatefulWidget in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have made the following reusable widget in Flutter. It is used to show a dropdown list of items taken from Cloud Firestore, and when a user selects an option it should be passed to the variable `answer`.

However when I use my widget `Survey Answer` the dropdown items show as expected, but I am unable to pass the selected option out from onChanged out of my widget - `print(widget.answer);` shows the right item in the Dart Console, the item selected from the dropdown menu, but when I use this widget on a different page and try to print out the value of the answer variable I just get `null` returned.

Can someone shed some light on this please?

Reusable widget:

```
class SurveyAnswer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String collection1;
  final String document;
  final String collection2;
  var answer;

  SurveyAnswer(
      {Key key,
      @required this.collection1,
      @required this.document,
      @required this.collection2,
      @required this.answer})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SurveyAnswerState createState() => _SurveyAnswerState();
}

class _SurveyAnswerState extends State<SurveyAnswer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance
            .collection(widget.collection1)
            .document(widget.document)
            .collection(widget.collection2)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Center(child: Text("Error"));
          else if (!snapshot.hasData)
            return Center(child: Text("Loading..."));
          else if (snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty)
            return Center(child: Container(width: 0, height: 0));
          else {
            List<DropdownMenuItem> answerItems = [];
            for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
              DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.documents[i];
              answerItems.add(
                DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text(
                    snap.documentID,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff303841)),
                  ),
                  value: "${snap.documentID}",
                ),
              );
            }
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                FormBuilderDropdown(
                  attribute: 'attribute',
                  hint: Text('Please choose an option'),
                  validators: [FormBuilderValidators.required()],
                  items: answerItems,
                  onChanged: (answerValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.answer = answerValue;
                      print(widget.answer);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

How the above is used in my app:

```
                SurveyAnswer(
                    collection1: 'MySurveys',
                    document: 'FirestoreTestSurvey',
                    collection2: 'a01',
                    answer: 'ans01'),
```

In this example, I want to create a variable `ans01` which returns the value selected in the dropdown menu.

The reason I have made a reusable widget for this is that each page has a lot of survey items and otherwise my code would be a mess.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should write callback function

```
class SurveyAnswer extends StatefulWidget {
  final String collection1;
  final String document;
  final String collection2;
  final Function(String) onAnswer;

  SurveyAnswer(
      {Key key,
      @required this.collection1,
      @required this.document,
      @required this.collection2,
      @required this.onAnswer})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SurveyAnswerState createState() => _SurveyAnswerState();
}
```

Change your on change method

```
onChanged: (answerValue) {
  widget.onAnswer(answerValue)
}
```

and use like this

```
SurveyAnswer(
       collection1: 'MySurveys',
        document: 'FirestoreTestSurvey',
        collection2: 'a01',
        onAnswer:  (ans) {
        print(ans)
})
```

Comment: Thank you - all I had to do for this is replace `print(ans)` with `ans01 = ans.toString();` to make `ans01` hold the value selected.